# Using strings from one column to search inside a string in another SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle, search, concatenation

I am trying to search inside a sentence using the string from another column in SQL. I have a large list of keywords and their rating on a scale from 1 to 6. I am trying to search through data pulled down from Twitter to see what people thought of certain movies (i.e. Wreck It Ralph) and give the movie an aggregate score. The problem I am having is that the data pulled from Twitter isn't broken up, but still in a full sentence. I can't figure out a way to search through the sentence for the keyword. Here is a query that works:

```
SELECT SUM(K.Score) 
FROM wreck_it_ralph WIR, Keyword K
WHERE t_text LIKE '%fantastic%'
       AND K.word = 'fantastic';
```

Here is a query I tried using concatenation, but was unsuccessful:

```
SELECT SUM(K.Score) 
FROM Wreck_it_Ralph WIR, Keyword k
WHERE t_text LIKE ('%' + k.word + '%');
```

Comment: SELECT SUM(K.Score) 
FROM Wreck_it_Ralph WIR, Keyword k
WHERE t_text LIKE '%' + k.word + '%';

Comment: The concatenated query seems like it would work.  What database server are you using?

Comment: It's one on campus. Oracle, I believe

Comment: try query in my comment

Comment: I fixed the query so it's 
    WHERE WIR.t_text LIKE ('%' + k.word + '%')
but now I get back an error that says "invalid number"

Comment: I tried your query. I got back the "invalid number" error

Comment: K.Score? K.Word datatype?

Comment: K.word is a varchar(20), score is a number

Comment: SELECT SUM(K.Score) 
FROM Wreck_it_Ralph WIR, Keyword k
WHERE t_text LIKE '%' || k.word || '%' GORDON LINOFF Concatenation in Oracle "||"

Answer (score 1):

Different databases have different ways of concatenating strings.  In Oracle or Postgres, try this:

```
SELECT SUM(K.Score) 
FROM Wreck_it_Ralph WIR, Keyword k
WHERE t_text LIKE '%' || k.word || '%'
```

In SQL Server or Sybase:

```
SELECT SUM(K.Score) 
FROM Wreck_it_Ralph WIR, Keyword k
WHERE t_text LIKE '%' + k.word + '%'
```

And in MySQL:

```
SELECT SUM(K.Score) 
FROM Wreck_it_Ralph WIR, Keyword k
WHERE t_text LIKE concat('%', k.word, '%')
```

Do note that you have a problem with partial word matches.  So, something "dislike" will match "like".  You may want to look into the full text capabilities of whichever database you are using, because that takes into account punctuation, full words, and stop-lists.

Comment: this query worked:
SELECT SUM(K.Score) 
FROM Wreck_it_Ralph WIR, Keyword k
WHERE t_text LIKE '%' || k.word || '%'

Comment: THANK YOU! I don't understand what these || symbols are doing though

Comment: @user2313460 . . . That happens to be the Oracle syntax for string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL-:

```
SELECT SUM(K.Score) 
FROM Wreck_it_Ralph WIR, Keyword k
WHERE t_text LIKE '%' + k.word + '%';
```